Issue with boundary condition in a GAM with a soap film smoother
I am currently trying to fit a GAM to model the number of fish detected on various acoustic receivers in a lake. These receivers are placed at specific locations and have a unique longitude and latitude. I am looking to model the number of fish detected at the receivers in each of 4 treatment group across the study period. I have done this in R with mgcv using the following code:
mod1 <- gam(number_of_fish ~ treatment +
              s(x, y,  by = treatment, k = 15,  bs = "so",
                xt = list(bnd = shap_bnd_ls, nmax = 1500)),
            data = filter(fish_num_final_utm, study_fortnight == 0),
            family = ziP(),
            method = "REML",
            knots = lake_knots)

Note that I am using a soap film smoother generated from a shapefile of my study system.
I have added a boundary condition so that the model knows to predict 0 fish at the lake edge, as follows. Note that shap_bnd_ls is my boundary list.
shap_bnd_ls <- lapply(nr,
                      function(n)
                        shap_bnd_ls[[n]] <- c(
                          shap_bnd_ls[[n]],
                          list(f = rep(0, length(shap_bnd_ls[[n]]$x))
                          )
                        )
)

The model appears to run OK. However, I don't think the boundary condition is working properly. Specially, the model appears to be consistently predicting non-zero numbers of fish at the lake edge (see below). I have tried adjusting 'k' values and using just a normal Poisson distribution, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Here are model predictions over the lake surface:

Any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
You can find the data, code, and shapefile here.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT 1
In line with Gavin's suggestion, I have tried to use family = nb() to get around the issue (I had trouble with family = ziplss()) and couldn't get the model to run).
Here is the rootogram:

I also keep getting fitted responses that exceed the maximum possible data values. I haven't found a way to fix this yet.
And here is the model plotted:

It doesn't look like this fixed the issue, as I am still getting >0 predictions around the boundary and in areas with no data.
I haven't been able to predict from the model as I used a + offset(log(max_unique_fish)) and always seem to have trouble when using this and trying to predict from the model using:
pred_mod1 <- broom.mixed::augment(mod1, newdata = newdata_df).
I also tried to convert the counts into proportions and run a beta regression to see if it fixed the issue. But my R on two different machines has crashed when trying to run the model, so something is not working there.

I wonder if this is just the use of ziP(), which is quite a brute of a family only allowing a constant zero-inflation, which is rarely whats needed. Do you see the same problem if you use the location scale version family = ziplss() (and adjust your model formula accordingly) or with something like family = nb()?

Thanks for the input Gavin. I have tried to use a negative binomial model, but this still doesn't seem to have fixed the issue (see edits to original post above).

After trying a few different iterations of the model with different distributions, it really seems like the soap-film smoother's boundary constraint is setting the partial effect of the smoother to zero at the boundary, rather than forcing the response variable to zero at the boundary. Is my understanding correct? And if so, is there a way to force the actual response variable to zero at the boundary?
